# Haskell: Flip parameters "inside" an anonymous function

Tags: haskell, lambda

My code looks like this:

```
myFunc x y = (map (flip (foo) y) x)

bar l t = map (myFunc l) [0..(t-1)]
```

How can `myFunc` be implemented as an anonymous function?

Comment: is this what you want? `bar l t = map (\y -> map (flip foo y) l) [0..(t-1)]`. Can you provide the types so it would easier. Also I think you can achive this better using applicatives

Comment: You could write it as a lambda expression (also known as *anonymous functions*). Or you could write the expression of `myFunc` in point-free style and use that directly in `bar`.

Comment: @Ismor Thank you, that did it! I knew it was somehow possible, but i couldn't wrap my head around it. Next time i will provide types and applicatives, i just thought this way the code would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

@Ismor 's answer

```
bar l t = map (\y -> map (flip foo y) l) [0..(t-1)]
```

solved my problem.